# How can I add BaseGameUtils to Chrome Cast project?

Tags: android, chromecast

I'm trying to add a Leader Board to a Chrome cast project and am getting errors. Android project in Android Studio.  In my gradle build - Error:  more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'

I understand why you don't want to use two different libraries with the same name, but not sure how to use the same library throughout the project. Here are the two uses of gms:
1)  Main activity has dependency on 'CastCompanionLibrary-android-master' which then uses google-play-services_lib.  I'm not sure which version of gms this uses, but the version number is referenced in the manifest. Is this just grabbing the version # of play services that they have installed on their phone?
2)  BaseGameUtils - has dependency on com.google.android.gms:play-services:+  (I think this is grabbing the most recent version of play-services, but doesn't match the other one.

```
MainActivity gradle file
dependencies {
    compile project(':BaseGameUtils')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':CastCompanionLibrary-android-master')
}

CastCompanionLibrary-android-master dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':android-support-v7-appcompat')
    compile project(':android-support-v7-mediarouter')
    compile project(':google-play-services_lib')
}

BaseGameUtils dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
}
```

So, the problem (I think) is these two versions of com.google.android.gms, but how do I rectify it so that they all use the same version. I've had almost 2 years of working with Android, but this is my first question on stack overflow. Help is appreciated - Is there a guru out there that has the answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have modified the gradle file for CCL since what you have there does not match with what CCL has in GitHub. The best approach is to only use the piece of play services that you need; for example CCL only needs the play-services-cast (besides the base, which will be pulled in automatically) so if you follow that pattern, things would look smaller (less possibility of running into the 64K dex limit) and less collisions.CCL, in Github, lists its dependency as:
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:6.5+'` so you might want to start using versions and also follow the recomendation I just made (same applies for any other code that you have and uses play services; just pull in what you really need)

Comment: Changed CCL dependencies to:  'compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:6.5+'    Still have the error.  Also changed     BaseGameUtils dependencies to:    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5+'  Still have the error. What am I missing here?   I wish that the error in Android studio was more informative, for example, providing the locations of where the two different libraries (of same name) are referenced.

Comment: For the game one, do you need the whole play services or just a smaller package (maybe play services for game)?

Comment: Trying to add a leader board. Looking at the "type-a-number challenge", I need the plus and games API's. So, the structure is the following:   VideoBrowserActivity uses CastCompanionLibrary and BaseGameUtils. Cast Companion library uses gms:play-services-cast:6.5+.  BaseGameUtils uses  plus and game services, but question is how to include dependency without getting gradle build error. I should add that I was able to switch dependency from google-play-services_lib to gms:play-services-cast:6.5+ and still get a build.

Comment: You can also try to restrict the play services on your game side to play-services-game and play-services-plus (similar to what you did for ccl) and see if that helps. After doing that, please copy the updated gradle files here (at least the dependencies) so we can see what you have.

Comment: Close to working at this point. Can't put all dependencies here because of character limit.  Here is BaseGameUtils dependencies:  dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:6.5+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:6.5+'
}

Comment: Error I am getting now:   Error:(32, 39) error: package com.google.android.gms.appstate does not exist.    So, the type-a-number challenge does use a few more API's (appstate and drive). Not sure how to add the appstate dependency to my project. Once this is found, I may get a build.

Comment: So, I've found the appstate location in the repository. There are no more errors for com.google.android.gms.   Now, I'm getting duplicate libraries for android.support.v7.appcompat.  This library was reference in both CastCompanionLibrary and also BaseGameUtils. Since VideoBrowserActivity was calling both of these, I moved the v7.appcompat dependency to VBA and removed it from the other two.  Here are the dependencies:

Comment: VBA:  dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.+'
    compile project(':CastCompanionLibrary-android-master')
    compile project(':BaseGameUtils')
}

Comment: CCL:  dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':android-support-v7-mediarouter')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:6.5+'
}       BGU:    dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:6.5+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:6.5+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appstate:6.5+'
}